# Gradient of $f(x) = a \oslash (b + a \odot x)$ w.r.t. $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: matrix-calculus

How to compute the gradient of

$f(x) := a \oslash (a \odot x + b) $,

with respect to $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\oslash$ is element-wise division, $\odot$ is element-wise multiplication, and $a , b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

---

The gradient should be a matrix, but I am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: You have a vector $(f^1(x_1,\cdots, x_n),\cdots , f^n(x_1,\cdots, x_n))$ which depends on $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and you want to calculate $\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x_j}(p_1,\cdots,p_n)$ for all $i,j$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$\eqalign{
v &= a \odot x + b\\
dv &= a \odot dx
}$$

Then, we can find the differential and gradient using the quotient rule:
$$\eqalign{
f &= a \oslash v\\
df &= (da \odot v - a \odot dv)\oslash(v\odot v) \\
&= -a \odot (a \odot dx) \oslash (v \odot v) \\
&= (-a\odot a \oslash (v\odot v)) \odot dx \\
&= (-f\odot f) \odot dx\\
&= -\operatorname{Diag}(f \odot f) dx
}$$

Thus:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -\operatorname{Diag}(f \odot f)
$$

Here Diag(.) is the operation which transforms a vector in a diagonal matrix. This is the standard procedure for converting a hadamard product in a matrix product. For example:

$$ a \odot b =\operatorname{Diag}(a)b = Ab $$